# Reprojecting: Different results in OGR and PROJ.4 for EPSG24373 (India)

Tags: coordinate-system, ogr, proj, pyproj

I need to convert EPSG4326 lon/lat tuples to EPSG24373 (Kalianpur 1880 / India zone III).  However, when using the Python bindings of OGR and PROJ.4 (pyproj), I get different results.

I wrote the following code:

```
LON, LAT = 76.661217, 15.183595

import numpy as np
from osgeo import ogr, osr

src_epsg = 4326
dst_epsg = 24373

source = osr.SpatialReference()
source.ImportFromEPSG(src_epsg)

target = osr.SpatialReference()
target.ImportFromEPSG(dst_epsg)

trans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)

point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt("POINT ({} {})".format(LON,
                                                         LAT))
point.Transform(trans)
print("OGR result: {}".format(point.ExportToWkt()))


from pyproj import Proj, transform
proj = Proj(init="epsg:{}".format(dst_epsg))
x1, y1 = proj(LON, LAT, radians=False)

print("pyproj result: {}".format((x1, y1)))
```

which yields the results

```
OGR result: POINT (2607326.263296442106366 542082.358424285310321)
pyproj result: (2384135.3043296584, 495679.3120856479)
```

From my expectation, the results should be identical, but they aren't.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Changing the lat/lon order doesn't give the results that the OP is seeing. I'm not sure it's a duplicate. andreash, can you check the pyproj definition for 24373 or give the +proj definition?

Comment: The point is that EPSG:24373 does not use meters, but Indian meters. The conversion factor gets missed in pyproj unless you set `preserve_units=true`. The offset is exactly the scaling factor for meters. The second answer of the linked question gives the right hint.

Comment: Oh, Indian yards. Now I understand. Thanks, @AndreJ !